# Object not replacing using spread operator

Tags: javascript, angular, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I want to replace existing object with new updated fields using spread operator. But I am not getting the correct result.

Below are my two objects.

```
let obj1 = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Michel",
    "age": 34,
    "email": "michel@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Abby",
    "age": 40,
    "email": "abby@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Gary",
    "age": 40,
    "email": "abby@gmail.com"
  }
]

let newObj = {
  "id": 3,
  "name": "Gary",
  "age": 23,
  "email": "gary@gmail.com"
}
```

I can do it with .map. Below is my code.

```
let result = obj1.map(item => {
  if (item.id === newObj.id) {
    return {...item, ...newObj};
  }
  return item;
});
```

But I do not want to run the loop and want to acheive by spread operator only.

Example for spread. Which is not working. It's not replacing the object. Instead creating one more.

```
[...obj1,  newObj];
```

Can someone help me?

[JSBIN CODE SNIPPET](https://jsbin.com/vihomezaze/1/edit?js,output)

Comment: The two snippets you've shared are doing two different tasks and doing them correctly. You can't expect to replace something without knowing what to replace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spread syntax doesn't replace the object within array like you used it. Using map is the simplest and understandable way. However if you want to use `spread syntax` you would first need to find the index to be replaced and then use slice on array

```js
let obj1 = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Michel",
    "age": 34,
    "email": "michel@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Abby",
    "age": 40,
    "email": "abby@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Gary",
    "age": 40,
    "email": "abby@gmail.com"
  }
]

let newObj = {
  "id": 3,
  "name": "Gary",
  "age": 23,
  "email": "gary@gmail.com"
}

const idx = obj1.findIndex(item => item.id === newObj.id);

obj1 = [...obj1.slice(0, idx), newObj, ...obj1.slice(idx + 1)];

console.log(obj1);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

> The **Object.assign()** method is used to copy the values of all enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target object. It will return the target object.

```js
let obj1 = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Michel",
    "age": 34,
    "email": "michel@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Abby",
    "age": 40,
    "email": "abby@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Gary",
    "age": 40,
    "email": "abby@gmail.com"
  }
]

let newObj = {
  "id": 3,
  "name": "Gary",
  "age": 23,
  "email": "gary@gmail.com"
}

Object.assign(obj1[2], newObj);

console.log(obj1)
```

**Using [.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to get the target obj**

```js
let obj1 = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Michel",
    "age": 34,
    "email": "michel@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Abby",
    "age": 40,
    "email": "abby@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Gary",
    "age": 40,
    "email": "abby@gmail.com"
  }
]

let newObj = {
  "id": 3,
  "name": "Gary",
  "age": 23,
  "email": "gary@gmail.com"
}

const targetObj = obj1.find(obj => obj.id === newObj.id)

Object.assign(targetObj, newObj);

console.log(obj1)
```

Answer (score 1):

you should normalize your data by id this way:

```
obj1 = {
   1: {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Michel",
    "age": 34,
    "email": "michel@gmail.com"
  },
  2: {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Abby",
    "age": 40,
    "email": "abby@gmail.com"
  },
  3: {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Gary",
    "age": 40,
    "email": "abby@gmail.com"
  }
}

newObj = {
  3: {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Gary",
    "age": 23,
    "email": "gary@gmail.com"
  }
}
```

this way you can use spread operator:

```
 { ...obj1, ...newObj }
```

in order to normalize you can use the reduce func this way:

```
const normalized = obj1.reduce((result, obj) => ({ ...result, [obj.id]: obj }), {})
```

Comment: This deserves the best answer!

Answer (score 0):

Spread operator is magic but it won't do whatever you want, you will have to loop over and replace the object. Instead of doing a [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), I would prefer [find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find). The use [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to achieve what you want.

```js
let obj1 = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Michel",
    "age": 34,
    "email": "michel@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Abby",
    "age": 40,
    "email": "abby@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Gary",
    "age": 40,
    "email": "abby@gmail.com"
  }
]

let newObj = {
  "id": 3,
  "name": "Gary",
  "age": 23,
  "email": "gary@gmail.com"
}


let foundOb = obj1.find(e => e.id === newObj.id);

Object.assign(foundOb, newObj)
console.log(obj1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use spread syntax in that way. One solution would be to find index of the object you want to replace by `id` property and then you could use spread syntax with `slice` method to create new array with replaced object.

```js
let obj1 = [{"id":1,"name":"Michel","age":34,"email":"michel@gmail.com"},{"id":2,"name":"Abby","age":40,"email":"abby@gmail.com"},{"id":3,"name":"Gary","age":40,"email":"abby@gmail.com"}]
let newObj = {"id":3,"name":"Gary","age":23,"email":"gary@gmail.com"}

const index = obj1.findIndex(({id}) => id == newObj.id)
const result = [...obj1.slice(0, index), newObj, ...obj1.slice(index + 1)]

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like:

`updatedObj = [obj1.map((entry) => entry.id !== newObj.id), newObj]`

This would give me the updated object with minimal syntax